# Undefined variable in program

Tags: php, inheritance

I am trying to write to write a program, but am getting some errors.

Base Car Class

1. current speed (property) – default value 0
2. accelerate (method)
3. drive (method)
4. brand (property) - default value ‘unknown’
5. max speed (property) - default value 0

Camaro Car Class

1. Inherits Base Car
2. brand (property) - default value ‘Chevy’
3. max speed (property) – default value 200

Code Scenario:
In this example I need to create an instance of Camaro and tell it to drive, I will assume it’s moving in a straight line and there are no other driving factors.  The car will accelerate until it hits its max speed.  It is required that drive will call accelerate. It is required accelerate will increment the current speed by 1.  Once the Camaro reaches max speed it should stop accelerating and print that it hit the cars max speed.  The execution of drive should then also stop.*

My Code is below which I tried.

```
<?php
class Car extends CI_Controller 
{



    public function accelerate($_brand,$_max)
    {
        if($this->$_speed<=$_max)
        {
            $this->$_speed += 1;
            return true;
        }   
        else 
        {
            echo $this->_brand . 'Reached max speed';
        }
        function drive()
        {
            $this->accelerate();
        }
    }
    public $_speed = 0; 
    public $_brand = 'unknown';
    public $_max = 0;
}
class Camaro extends Car
{
    public $_brand = 'Chevy';
    public $_max = 100;
}

$car1 = new Camaro();
echo $car1 -> accelerate($_brand,$_max);
?>
```

Comment: Count your braces..... using proper indenting helps

Comment: `$this->$_speed` are you sure this is valid PHP code?

Comment: Can you tell us EXACTLY what kind of error occurs? Please post any error messages.

Comment: the error is Undefined variable: _brand and Undefined variable: _max on line 34.

Comment: @MarkBaker do you think that it should be `echo $car1 -> drive($car1->_brand, $car1->_max);` instead of `echo $car1 -> accelerate($_brand,$_max);`? I mean, logically thinking

Answer (score 1):

Lets get rid of some little horrors in the code and reformat it ;)

**1)** instead of `$this->$_speed` use `$this->_speed`

**2)**  put all property declarations at the top of your class

```
class Car extends CI_Controller 
{

    public $_speed = 0;
    public $_brand = 'unknown';
    public $_max = 0;

    public function accelerate($_brand,$_max)
    {
        if($this->_speed<=$_max)
        {
            $this->_speed += 1;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            echo $this->_brand . 'Reached max speed';
        }

    }

   public function drive()
   {
       $this->accelerate();
   }

}
class Camaro extends Car
{
    public $_brand = 'Chevy';
    public $_max = 100;
}

$car1 = new Camaro();
echo $car1 -> accelerate($car1->_brand, $car1->_max);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried the above one but still getting error. Undefined variable: _brand and Undefined variable: _max on line 34.

Comment: @user3622254 updated answer `$car1->_brand` has to be passed to `accelerate()` instead of simply `$_brand`

Comment: Hi Mark..Actually it is required that drive should call accelerate. Am I doing it wrong or is any other right way. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you need to call `echo $car1 -> drive($car1->_brand, $car1->_max);` then?

Comment: I applied ur suggestion and error are gone. But I am still getting warnings.                                                                                       Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ci/application/controllers/Car.php:36)

Comment: Also is there any option that it should print the speed till car reaches the max speed. Where I need to put "for loop" or any other loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the code bellow:

1) in Car class:

```
if($this->_speed<=$_max)
{

  $this->_speed += 1;

  return true;

}
```

2) Demo

```
$car1 = new Camaro();

echo $car1->accelerate($car1->_brand, $car1->_max);
```

Comment: <br/> I implemented it and I am getting this warning. <br/>                            A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ci/application/controllers/Car.php:36)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 573

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ci/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Comment: Do Google that ^ @user3622254 you will quickly find the reason for that warning message, and more than likely find that Q&A from Stack.

Comment: @Pao Is there any way to print the speeds till it reaches the maximum. Where I need to put for loop.

Comment: @user3622254, try with echo $car1->_speed; Sorry if cannot help you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution. Thanks for the help. This is the final program which worked for me.

```
<?php
class Car extends CI_Controller 
{

public $_speed = 0;
public $_brand = 'unknown';
public $_max = 0;

public function accelerate($_brand,$_max)
{
    for ($_speed = 0; $_speed <= $_max; $_speed++)
             {
                    if ($this->_speed <$_max) 
                     {
                        echo "<p>$_speed<p>";
                     }
            }
            echo $this->_brand . ' reached max speed.';
}
public function drive()
{
   $this->accelerate();
}

}
 class Camaro extends Car
{
 public $_brand = 'Chevy';
 public $_max = 100;
}

$car1 = new Camaro();
echo $car1 -> accelerate($car1->_brand, $car1->_max);
?>
//output 1 2 3 ... 100 Chevy reached max speed.
```