# stuck in FOR Loop

Tags: php, performance, loops, inheritance, for-loop

Base Car Class

1. current speed (property) – default value 0
2. accelerate (method)
3. drive (method)
4. brand (property) - default value ‘unknown’
5. max speed (property) - default value 0

Camaro Car Class

Inherits Base Car

1. brand (property) - default value ‘Chevy’
2. max speed (property) – default value 200

Code Scenario: In this example I need to create an instance of Camaro and tell it to drive, I will assume it’s moving in a straight line and there are no other driving factors.  The car will accelerate until it hits its max speed.  It is required that drive will call accelerate. It is required accelerate will increment the current speed by 1.  Once the Camaro reaches max speed it should stop accelerating and print that it hit the cars max speed.  The execution of drive should then also stop.

My Code is below which I tried where I am trying to print the speeds till it reaches the maximum.Where I should put the for loop to print all the speeds incremented by 1 till the max i.e. 100.Something like below
1
2
3
...100

```
<?php
class Car extends CI_Controller 
{

public $_speed = 0;
public $_brand = 'unknown';
public $_max = 0;

public function accelerate($_brand,$_max)
{
    if($this->_speed<=$_max)
    {
        for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++)
        {
            $this->_speed += 1;
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo $this->_brand . 'Reached max speed';
    }

}

public function drive()
{
   $this->accelerate();
}

}
class Camaro extends Car
{
public $_brand = 'Chevy';
public $_max = 100;
}

$car1 = new Camaro();
echo $car1 -> accelerate($car1->_brand, $car1->_max);
?>
```

Comment: Ask your question to point , you risk being flaged .

Comment: @jimmyobonyo, voted to close. It could be a good question, but has too many issues for a moderator to fix imho. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @benjamin this program has no errors. It just I want to print speeds using FOR loop something like 1 2 3...100 and I am unable to do it. I am new to this community so pardon me. Thanks

Comment: Don't take my vote personal, it is just review process to keep SO usage efficient. People are going to help others for free on this site, so they should only have to do the minimal amount of work to answer a question. Welcome to SO, @user3622254.

Comment: **Possible duplicate of:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360564/undefined-variable-in-program/34365919#34365919 **Solved there**

Answer (score 0):

```
public function accelerate($_brand,$_max)
{
        for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++)
        {
            $this->_speed += 1;
            if ($this->_speed ==$_max) {
                 echo 'max speed';
                 break; //use it to stop accelarating
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: it is still printing "max speed" 100 times. how to print speed..something like 1 2 3 4....till 100